# While continues to evaluate despite encountering false

Tags: java, while-loop, stack

I encountered a strange behaviour of the while loop. The statement is as follows:

```
while (!s.empty() && (Character)s.peek()!='k')
{/*some code*/}
```

and despite getting false in the first condition, the while loops continues to evaluate the second one resulting in an exception being thrown. Why? Isn't it supposed to exit since I'm using the '&&' operator?

**EDIT:** java.util.EmptyStackException on peek()

**EDIT 2 (since you wonder if it's related to multi-threading):** I'm using Swing but the app is quite simple. I'm trying to do Infix Notation->Reverse Polish Notation converter. Posting full, yet probably unfinished method below. The exception appears below the line

```
if (curChar=='+' || curChar=='-'){
```

on `peek()` method.

```
public void convert(){
    Stack rpnStack= new Stack();
    curPos=0;
    expression=inputExp.getText();
    expressionRpn="";

    while (curPos<expression.length()){
        nextChar();
        if (Character.isDigit(curChar)){
            while (Character.isDigit(curChar) || curChar=='.'){
            expressionRpn+=curChar;
            nextChar();
            }
            curPos--;
            curChar=expression.charAt(curPos);
        } else 
        if (curChar=='('){
            rpnStack.push(curChar);
        } else
        if (curChar==')'){
            while (!rpnStack.empty() && (Character)rpnStack.peek()!='('){
                expressionRpn+=rpnStack.pop();
            }
        } else
        if (curChar=='+' || curChar=='-'){
            while (!(rpnStack.empty()) && (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='+' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='-' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='('){
                expressionRpn+=rpnStack.pop();
            }
            rpnStack.push(curChar);
        } else
        if (curChar=='*' || curChar=='/'){
            while (!rpnStack.empty() && (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='+' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='-' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='(' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='*' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='/'){
                expressionRpn+=rpnStack.pop();
            }
            rpnStack.push(curChar);
        } else
        if (curChar=='^'){
            while (!rpnStack.empty() && (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='+' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='-' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='(' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='*' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='/' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='^'){
                expressionRpn+=rpnStack.pop();
            }
            rpnStack.push(curChar);
        } 
    }
    while (!rpnStack.empty()){
        expressionRpn+=rpnStack.pop();
    }
    rpnLabel.setText(expressionRpn);
}
```

Comment: Might just be how it evaluates.. you could solve this by moving the peek section into an if/else inside the while loop

Comment: Can you show some more code? Obviously, if the first expression is indeed false, it will terminate, so the error needs to be somewhere else.

Comment: What is "some code"? What is the stack trace of the exception? Which line does it refer to?

Comment: How do you know that the `peek` method is actually called?

Comment: I'm getting the 'java.util.EmptyStackException' on peek() when debugging. The result of the first condition is indeed false.

Comment: Are you removing items from the stack in the while loop body?

Comment: Put peek inside the while loop and break on your condition for that character

Comment: @bdkosher Yes, but the debugger never reaches that place.

Comment: @PramusPL What's preventing the items from being removed then? That sounds like the real problem at hand.

Comment: @bdkosher The problem I have is not popping out the items from the stack but with the exception that's thrown when it shouldn't be. I realise that the workaround proposed by cricket_007 would work but still, it's a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: What class is this? It doesn't look like the `Queue` interface...

Comment: Never mind, I assume it's a `Stack`.

Comment: Can your code be running simultaneously in multiple threads? That could cause this.

Comment: The debugger does not always tell the truth. If you have watches on `s` doing some operations, you can actually manipulate it's state, causing strange behaviour.  I suggest you post the full code. The error is not in the `while`, but somewhere else.

Comment: Full method in edited post.

Comment: which line exactly of your method throws an exception?

Comment: Answered in the question

Comment: I think you need to put all your peeks into parentheses inside the if: `a && (b || c || d)`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html Read what it says about precedence

Comment: @ciamej This is the answer. Without parentheses what the compiler sees is this: (!rpnStack.empty() && (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='+') || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='-' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='(' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='*' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='/' || (Character)rpnStack.peek()=='^'